# Composer - require another package from my package/bundle but it just won't autoload. Solved in two other ways but not clean enough

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I'm using Symfony 2.3 and Composer and using Composer to install my bundle from a remote repository. Doing this on its own works fine, but the problem I have is when I try to require another package from my Symfony2 bundle.

My bundle is in the src/ folder.

I've added this to my bundle's composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "rackspace/php-opencloud": "1.10.*"
},
```

Everything installs but I now need to ensure the classes are autoloaded (registering namespaces I think), but it just won't do it.

I have actually solved this problem in two other ways, but they are not clean enough. I want my bundle to handle the dependency not the app folder or main Symfony2 composer.json.

Solutions that aren't good enough:

(1) If I add the Rackspace package to my symfony2/composer.json then everything works perfectly. But this is poor as the dependency is on my bundle not the whole Symfony2 framework.

(2) If I add these to app/autoload.php then it also works:

```
$loader->add('OpenCloud', __DIR__.'/../src/rackspace/php-opencloud/lib');
$loader->add('Guzzle\\Http', __DIR__.'/../src/guzzle/http');
$loader->add('Guzzle\\Common', __DIR__.'/../src/guzzle/common');
```

...but this is messy and again the dependency is on the bundle not the application.

I have tried various variations of this (in my bundle's composer.json) but it just won't work:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "OpenCloud": ["rackspace/php-opencloud/lib/", "rackspace/php-opencloud/tests/"] }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, only relative paths are required.

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "OpenCloud": ["lib/", "tests/"] }
}
```

I did not test with multiple paths for the same prefix. This may not be supported.

You can alternatively use the classmap autoloader, which will go through an entire folder and generate a static map from them. No prefix required.

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": ["lib/", "tests/"]
}
```

I rarely saw tests being included in the autoloading for external application however. PHPUnit handles class loading just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately none of this makes a difference. However, I've found that everything is actually being configured exactly as I want it, but the problem is something else. Inside src/composer/autoload_namespaces.php it has configured everything as I would expect. The problem is it doesn't run/recognise the autoload_real.php file (which uses the autoload_namespace.php file). It just ignores it. I have tested by forcing this to be used (really dirty method). How do I get autoload_real.php to run by default. The vendor/composer/autoload_real.php DOES run by default.

Comment: Composer builds the autoload files. They should not be edited manually.